# Using a nested group by statement or sub query to filter this result sets

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

This question is a continuation of [Changing this query to group rows and filter out all rows apart from the one with smallest value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12331810/) but with an extra bit at the end....

I have the following results set:

```
275     72.87368055555555555555555555555555555556   foo    70
275     72.87390046296296296296296296296296296296   foo    90 
113     77.06431712962962962962962962962962962963   foo    80
113     77.07185185185185185185185185185185185185   foo    60
```

that I got from this query:

```
SELECT id, (tbl2.date_modified - tbl1.date_submitted)/86400, some_value
FROM tbl1, tbl2, tbl3
WHERE tbl1.id = tbl2.fid 
AND tbl1.id = tbl3.fid
```

Notice there are 4 rows with 2 ids.  I wanted to filter the rows to get only the minimum number in the second column.  This fixed it:

```
SELECT id, min((tbl2.date_modified - tbl1.date_submitted)/86400), max(some_value)
FROM tbl1, tbl2, tbl3
WHERE tbl1.id = tbl2.fid 
AND tbl1.id = tbl3.fid
GROUP BY tbl1.id
```

so I got:

```
275     72.87368055555555555555555555555555555556   foo    70
113     77.06431712962962962962962962962962962963   foo    80
```

How can I change it to do the same but not include rows where the are other rows with `some_value=90` ?  I.e.

```
113     77.06431712962962962962962962962962962963   foo    80
```

I think I need some nested group or nested query ?!

Many thanks :).

Comment: NO, not that simple.. there could be say `5` rows for `1` `id` where one row has the `some_value` of `90`.. I would then want to exclude ALL `5` rows.

Comment: Where are all your columns coming from, specifically `id` and `some_value`?

Comment: `id` is coming from `tbl1`, `some_value` is coming from `tbl2`.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT id, 
  min((tbl2.date_modified - tbl1.date_submitted)/86400), 
  max(some_value)
FROM tbl1, tbl2, tbl3
WHERE tbl1.id = tbl2.fid 
  AND tbl1.id = tbl3.fid
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT id 
                  FROM tbl2 
                  WHERE tbl1.id = tbl2.fid
                    AND some_value = 90)
GROUP BY tbl1.id
```

Or using ANSI join syntax:

```
SELECT id, 
  min((tbl2.date_modified - tbl1.date_submitted)/86400), 
  max(some_value)
FROM tbl1
INNER JOIN tbl2
   ON tbl1.id = tbl2.fid 
INNER JOIN tbl3
   ON tbl1.id = tbl3.fid
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT id 
                  FROM tbl2 
                  WHERE tbl1.id = tbl2.fid
                    AND some_value = 90)
GROUP BY tbl1.id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `where not exists`

```
select a.id, min((b.date_modified - a.date_submitted)/86400), max(some_value)
  from tbl1 a
  join tbl2 b
    on a.id = b.fid 
  join tbl3 c
    on a.id = c.fid
 where not exists ( select 1 
                      from tbl2
                     where fid = a.id 
                       and some_value >= 90 )
 group by a.id
```

or `not in`

```
select a.id, min((b.date_modified - a.date_submitted)/86400), max(some_value)
  from tbl1 a
  join tbl2 b
    on a.id = b.fid 
  join tbl3 c
    on a.id = c.fid
 where a.id not in ( select fid 
                       from tbl2 
                        and some_value >= 90 )
 group by a.id
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you should write your query using standard JOIN syntax.  If you just want to exclude rows with some_value = 90, do this in the WHERE clause:

```
SELECT id, min((tbl2.date_modified - tbl1.date_submitted)/86400), max(some_value)
FROM tbl1 join
     tbl2
     on tbl1.id = tbl2.fid join
     tbl3
     on tbl1.id = tbl3.fid
WHERE somevalue = 90
GROUP BY tbl1.id
```

I'm not sure what you mean by "not include rows where the are other rows with some_value=90".  If what you mean to exclude all result rows if there is a 90, then use a HAVING clause:

```
SELECT id, min((tbl2.date_modified - tbl1.date_submitted)/86400), max(some_value)
FROM tbl1 join
     tbl2
     on tbl1.id = tbl2.fid join
     tbl3
     on tbl1.id = tbl3.fid
GROUP BY tbl1.id
HAVING sum(case when somevalue = 90 then 1 else 0 end) > 0
```

Another tip:  always include aliases for your columns, so everyone knows what table they are coming from.